# run nightwatchjs in watch mode

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm searching for the equivalent of mocha:

`mocha test.spec.js -w`

opening nigtwatch manually on every change burns a lot of time during test writing.

any ideas of this?

I've checked nightwatch docs and google, nothing came up

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, there isn't a `--watch` mode or command for nightwatch. This is only an answer in that what I've seen confirms that this doesn't seem to exist.

Here are the sources that led me to this conclusion, including possible leads for other solutions:

1. I've found an issue in the nightwatch repo asking about that in 2016: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1061. The answer then was

> 'No, but you can use something like the `grunt-contrib-watch` module.'

2. I found a stackoverflow question in 2018 that talks about how nightwatch, and other things using selenium, always return `exit code 1`: [Nightwatch.js always returns exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49425522). That leads me to believe that nightwatch always exits its tests. The question was asking about integrate Nightwatch.js tests in a Jenkins Job. A comment offers a possible solution for that, so maybe it's possible to make a wrapper for nightwatch this way:

> This happens with other selenium based libraries as well. I think I ran into this issue with protractor in the past. The way we tackled it was by parsing the output instead of using the exit code and looked for any failures. If none were found then we returned `0` explicitly... you can check for failed tests using `browser.currentTest.results.failed` and then figure out a way to pass or fail your build based on that.