# Nightwatch.js always returns exit code 1

Tags: node.js, jenkins, cucumber, nightwatch.js, exit-code

I try to integrate my Nightwatch.js tests in a Jenkins Job. I want the Jenkins build to fail if the tests will fail and I want the build to pass if all tests will pass. But I recognized that Nightwatch always returns the `exit code 1`, doesn't matter if the tests will pass or fail. But I expect that the `exit code 0` will be return if all tests will pass.

Does anyone have a solution for that issue? I use `nightwatch@0.9.19` in combination with `nightwatch-cucumber@9.0.0`.

This is my Nightwatch call:

```
./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --env chrome
```

And if all tests were passed:

```
./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --env chrome
echo $?
#Output: 1, but I expect 0
```

If I start the tests with the Nightwatch in last line and the test will pass, then the NPM command will fail because of the wrong `exit code 1` in that case:

```
> #!/usr/bin/env sh
> ./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --env $1 $2
>


Starting selenium server... started - PID:  86384
...
 ✔ Element <input#login-form-username> was visible after 41 milliseconds.

 ✔ Element <input#login-form-password> was visible after 36 milliseconds.

 ✔ Element <input#login> was visible after 34 milliseconds.
.
 ✔ Element <a#header-details-user-fullname> was visible after 6438 milliseconds.

 ✔ Element <a#log_out> was present after 22 milliseconds.
..

1 scenario (1 passed)
4 steps (4 passed)
0m16.298s

true
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! e2e-web-tests@1.0.0 test: `scripty "chrome" "--tag=lcm-128"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the e2e-web-tests@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/GRme/.npm/_logs/2018-03-22T11_08_36_903Z-debug.log
```

Comment: If I remember right, this isn't just a nightwatch issue. This happens with other selenium based libraries as well. I think I ran into this issue with protractor in the past. The way we tackled it was by parsing the output instead of using the exit code and looked for any failures. If none were found then we returned `0` explicitly. This was at my last job so I'm having a hard time remembering but I'm pretty sure that is why we had to do it that way. Because we were having the same problem with TFS.

Comment: do you know how you parsed the output? is there an lib to do that?

Comment: We created a custom build step in TFS to handle it. I'm not too familiar with Jenkins so I can't say if it allows you to create custom build steps or not. In any case, you should have access to the output in the global `afterEach()` function. You could write something there to parse the output and look for failures. We didn't use a library, just parsed the output and used a regex matcher to look for failed tests. I wish I had an example to show you but I don't have access to that code anymore as I no longer work at that company.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was misleading. I don't see the complete output in the `afterEach()` but you can check for failed tests using `browser.currentTest.results.failed` and then figure out a way to pass or fail your build based on that. Perhaps use some sort of flag that you can flip if you have any failures during the test run.

Comment: Hey @Martin, see if the accepted answer here will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596304/failing-a-jenkins-job-when-nightwatch-test-assertion-fails-in-browserstack#answers

Comment: It‘s not so easy. I‘m working for a big company as freepancer and it would take a long time to enable a new Jenkins plugin. The processes are very long, you know? So, I try to find a solution outside of Jenkins to have a possible solution in my own hand.

Comment: I understand. Wish I knew a workaround for you. I tried playing around with it a bit to see if I could come up with something but so far I've come up empty handed.

Comment: Thank you for your great motivation. If you have any solution or something like a solution, please ping me 